# How to adding multiple credit card using authorize.net .Net API?

Tags: asp.net, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am using authorize.net development account for testing payment gateway.

Our customer wanted that he should be adding multiple credit card and those credit card information should not be saved in our local database. Those credit card information should be saved in the authorize.net database or somewhere by the authorize.net api, later on the customer can only choose any of those saved credit cards from dropdown list without giving all the information about credit card again and payment should be made for that particular card.

Is there any way to achieve this using authorize.net for .Net technologies?

Comment: I guess authorize.net will not send you list of credit card numbers back you will have to store it in your own DB.

Comment: Our client does not want us to store credit card information in local database.

Comment: Yes, use their CIM API.

Answer (score 0):

[Customer Profiles](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/customer_profiles.html) allows you to securely store sensitive card data on Authorize.Net servers and store tokens within your database.  Your application can use the tokens for payment transactions.  You can learn more in the [API Reference](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles) and try it using the live console.